# How to add Username and Password to Rethinkdb connection?

Tags: rethinkdb

How to add username and password to `rethinkdb` connection?

In my network there are 100 plus machines. Out which only 2 machines are under my control.
Out of 2, one is virtual machine and one is physical machine.

If i run `rethinkdb` on virtual machine with below command

```
rethinkdb --bind all
```

Now my `rethinkdb http:// ip:8080` is exposed to all machines in the network. How to set username and password to restrict others?

If i use `localhost:8080` in the virtual machine, administrative HTTP connection is useless as it can't be accessed neither on the physical machine nor on the virtual machine.

How do i solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't provide an authentication system yet, see https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/266

The best way for is probably not to start rethinkdb with the --bind all flags.

You can still access the web interface with a ssh tunnel.
If you're on linux, the command is

```
ssh -D <PORT> <LOGIN>@<MACHINE>
```

Then set up your browser to use the ssh tunnel. In chrome it's in settings > proxy settings
Set the socks host to  and port to  you use before.

Then if you hit machine:8080 in your browser, you should be able to see the adminstration http interface.

Answer (score 10):

**Procedure to create ssh tunnel and access localhost of other machines:**

My virtual Machine is linux
and my physical Machine is Mac

step1: Access virtual machine and start rethinkdb

```
user@mac:~# ssh user@linux
user@linux:~# rethinkdb
```

step2: create a SSH tunnel to access locahost:8080 of linux machine

```
user@mac:~# ssh -L 9000:localhost:8080 user@linux
user@linux:~#
```

step3: open a browser and point to

```
http://localhost:9000
```

Thats it! You need not change any browser settings!

Resource:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=VdkLejEN3So